# urllib2's result differs from that of a web browser

Tags: python, request, response, urllib2

I'm writing a function in `aws-lambda`. The function is simple. It just gets request from specific website.

Lambda function in python2 is like below. `import urllib2` is included also.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    url = "https://www.amazon.co.jp/s/field-keywords=4548967337259"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    #print response

    return response.read()
```

I take the returned value to my `ruby on rails` server and tried to parse for the necessary info.

On the website, the tag and relative information are shown like below.

```
    <a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" target="_blank" 
rel="noopener" href="https://www.amazon.co.jp/GOTHAM-
%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89-%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%83%B3-
%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4-
%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88-
%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9-Blu-ray/dp/B071K5VZTL/ref=sr_1_1?
ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1505293516&amp;sr=8-1&amp;keywords=4548967337259">
```

However, if I take `response` and use `read()` method to transfer, it looks like this.

```
<a class=\"a-link-normal a-text-normal\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\" 
href=\"https://www.amazon.co.jp/GOTHAM-%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89-
%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%83%B3-
%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4-
%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88-
%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9-Blu-ray/dp/B071K5VZTL\">
```

Why does this happen and how can I avoid this?

Actually I tried something like `response.json()` but it was not able to make as `json` form entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing a `User-Agent` header:

```
import urllib2

def lambda_handler(...):
    request = urllib2.Request("http://www.google.com",
                           headers={"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0"})
    return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: can you explain the difference with headers and without it?

Comment: @jh.shin you can "fool" the server into thinking you're a web browser. Without it Seems it will serve you different content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the response to the string function:

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = "https://www.amazon.co.jp/s/field-keywords=4548967337259"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return str(response.read()) #here, casting as a string
```

Comment: what is big difference between `response.read()` and casting it as a string?